# How to slice specific characters in every item of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to bold the first four characters of every item of an array (in this case a list), but all I know how to do is select whole strings:

```
$("li").slice(0).css("font-weight", "Bold");
```

How can I specify which of each string's characters I want to slice?

Comment: `.slice(beginindex,endindex)`?

Comment: Familiar with that, but here it would bold the entirety of each item sliced. I want to select all of them [slice(0)], then select the first 4 characters of each [slice(0,3)?].

Comment: or you can use :gt or :lt selector of jquery

Comment: do you wanna apply css effects on first dom? then. `$("li").eq(0).css("font-weight", "Bold");` OR  `$("li").first().css("font-weight", "Bold");`

Comment: Is there a need to consider only alpha character ? Meaning, in `<li>Foo Bar</li>`, is it necessary to consider the `B` as the fourth character (so not counting the space) ?

Comment: Guradio: :gt and :lt only changed which of the array's items I sliced.
Mung: This bolded the first item's whole string.
Plotisateur: Nope. (Jeff and Ferhad's methods did it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('li').each(function() {
    var $li = $(this);
    var txt = $li.text();
    $li.text(txt.substring(4));
    $li.prepend($('<b/>').text(txt.substring(0,4)));
});
```

That iterates through each `<li>` tag and replaces the inner text with a bold tag containing the first four characters, and the remaining original text afterwards.

You could switch the `<b>` to a `<span>` to have more control over the style.  You could also experiment with `.html()` if you need to preserve other markup within each list item.

Comment: That did it! Thank you

Comment: Sure thing! Remember to accept one of the answers you receive if they helped resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which may help you:

```js
$("li").each(function() {
  var len = $(this).text().length,
      text1 = $(this).text().slice(0, 4),
      text2 = $(this).text().slice(5, len);
  $(this).html('<b style="color:red">' + text1 + '</b>' + text2);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>how-to-slice</li>
  <li>specific</li>
  <li>characters</li>
  <li>in-every</li>
  <li>item-of-an-array</li>
</ul>
```